# Reactjs/Reactstrap focus next input by ref not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have 4 inputs for entering `otp` and I want to auto focus next input after fill current input, then I create `ref`

```
this.textInput1 = React.createRef();
this.textInput2 = React.createRef();
this.textInput3 = React.createRef();
this.textInput4 = React.createRef();
```

And my function to check input is:

```
checkOTP = (e, otp) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
//... some other code
    if (otp === 'otp1' && value.length === 1) { // if you fill input 1
        this.textInput2.current.focus() // it should focus input 2 but won't work
    }
}
```

And here are inputs:

```
<Input ref={this.textInput1} type="text" maxLength="1" autoComplete="off" name="otp1" onChange={(e)=>this.checkOTP(e, 'otp1')} />
<Input ref={this.textInput2} type="text" maxLength="1" autoComplete="off" name="otp2" onChange={(e)=>this.checkOTP(e, 'otp2')} />
<Input ref={this.textInput3} type="text" maxLength="1" autoComplete="off" name="otp3" onChange={(e)=>this.checkOTP(e, 'otp3')} />
<Input ref={this.textInput4} type="text" maxLength="1" autoComplete="off" name="otp4" onChange={(e)=>this.checkOTP(e, 'otp4')} />
```

But by enter first otp it won't focus second, nothing happen, any idea?
Using `react 17.0.2` with `reactstrap`

**Live Demo:**

```js
const { Input } = Reactstrap;

class OTP extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
        this.textInput1 = React.createRef();
        this.textInput2 = React.createRef();
        this.textInput3 = React.createRef();
        this.textInput4 = React.createRef();
  }
  
    checkOTP = (e, otp) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        if (otp === 'otp1' && value.length === 1) {
            this.textInput2.current.focus()
        }
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="d-flex">
      <Input ref={this.textInput1} type="text" maxLength="1" autoComplete="off" name="otp1" onChange={(e)=>this.checkOTP(e, 'otp1')} />
<Input ref={this.textInput2} type="text" maxLength="1" autoComplete="off" name="otp2" onChange={(e)=>this.checkOTP(e, 'otp2')} />
<Input ref={this.textInput3} type="text" maxLength="1" autoComplete="off" name="otp3" onChange={(e)=>this.checkOTP(e, 'otp3')} />
<Input ref={this.textInput4} type="text" maxLength="1" autoComplete="off" name="otp4" onChange={(e)=>this.checkOTP(e, 'otp4')} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<OTP />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/6.3.1/reactstrap.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Which version of react are you using ? there is a hook for ref 'useRef' + can you share a codepen or jsfiddle since the code you posted seems valid :)

Comment: @JiaSH my version is `17.0.2`, okay I'll try to make a codepen

Comment: It seems like Reactstrap uses a different prop name for `ref`, try `innerRef` instead? https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/Input.js

Comment: @Vicky oh you saved my day, look like problem solved! Thanks!

Comment: @tourtravel you're welcome! :)

Comment: @Vicky thanks! maybe turn your comment into an answer so clearer